# Error: Installing SciPy in Windows 10 64bit using pip (Python 3.5.2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, pip, windows-10

I want to install SciPy package in my system through pip (command line). It is a Windows 10 64-bit system. I have installed Python 3.5.2. I have already installed other Machine Learning and statistical packages like numpy, sklearn, pandas, matplotlib, sympy, jupyter, ipython and nose. They have all installed successfully without any errors.

I am using this command to install scipy from pip:

---

> **C:\Projects\Kaggle>pip install scipy**

---

But while installing scipy, I am getting this error:

> C:\Projects\Kaggle>pip install scipy Collecting scipy   Using cached
>   scipy-0.18.1.tar.gz Installing collected packages: scipy   Running
>   setup.py install for scipy ... error
>       Complete output from command c:\users\i319268\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\python.exe -u
>   -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\i319268\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-b1nkbg30\scipy\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record C:\Users\i319268\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-06bz__e6-record\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
>
> ```
> Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
> with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:
>
>   - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
>                            release)
>   - `pip install scipy`   (last SciPy release on PyPI)
>
>
> lapack_opt_info:
> openblas_lapack_info:
>   libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\i319268\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib',
> ```
>
> 'C:\',
>   'c:\users\i319268\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\libs']
>         NOT AVAILABLE
>
> ```
> lapack_mkl_info:
>   libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\i319268\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib',
> ```
>
> 'C:\',
>   'c:\users\i319268\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\libs']
>         NOT AVAILABLE
>
> ```
> atlas_3_10_threads_info:
> Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
> c:\users\i319268\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:639:
> ```
>
> UserWarning: Specified path
>   C:\projects\numpy-wheels\windows-wheel-builder\atlas-builds\atlas-3.11.38-sse2-64\lib
>   is invalid.
>         warnings.warn('Specified path %s is invalid.' % d)
>       
>         NOT AVAILABLE
>
> ```
> atlas_3_10_info:
> <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
>   NOT AVAILABLE
>
> atlas_threads_info:
> Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
> <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
>   NOT AVAILABLE
>
> atlas_info:
> <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
>   NOT AVAILABLE
>
> c:\users\i319268\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1532:
> ```
>
> UserWarning:
>           Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
>           Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
>           numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
>           the ATLAS environment variable.
>         warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.**doc**)
>       lapack_info:
>         libraries lapack not found in ['c:\users\i319268\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib',
>   'C:\',
>   'c:\users\i319268\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\libs']
>         NOT AVAILABLE
>
> ```
> c:\users\i319268\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1543:
> ```
>
> UserWarning:
>           Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
>           Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
>           numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
>           the LAPACK environment variable.
>         warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.**doc**)
>       lapack_src_info:
>         NOT AVAILABLE
>
> ```
> c:\users\i319268\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1546:
> ```
>
> UserWarning:
>           Lapack sources not found.
>           Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
>           numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
>           the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
>         warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.**doc**)
>         NOT AVAILABLE
>
> ```
> Running from scipy source directory.
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "C:\Users\i319268\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-b1nkbg30\scipy\setup.py",
> ```
>
> line 415, in 
>           setup_package()
>         File "C:\Users\i319268\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-b1nkbg30\scipy\setup.py",
>   line 411, in setup_package
>           setup(**metadata)
>         File "c:\users\i319268\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py",
>   line 135, in setup
>           config = configuration()
>         File "C:\Users\i319268\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-b1nkbg30\scipy\setup.py",
>   line 335, in configuration
>           config.add_subpackage('scipy')
>         File "c:\users\i319268\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py",
>   line 1000, in add_subpackage
>           caller_level = 2)
>         File "c:\users\i319268\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py",
>   line 969, in get_subpackage
>           caller_level = caller_level + 1)
>         File "c:\users\i319268\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py",
>   line 906, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
>           config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
>         File "scipy\setup.py", line 15, in configuration
>           config.add_subpackage('linalg')
>         File "c:\users\i319268\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py",
>   line 1000, in add_subpackage
>           caller_level = 2)
>         File "c:\users\i319268\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py",
>   line 969, in get_subpackage
>           caller_level = caller_level + 1)
>         File "c:\users\i319268\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py",
>   line 906, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
>           config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
>         File "scipy\linalg\setup.py", line 20, in configuration
>           raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
>       numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found
>
> ```
> ---------------------------------------- Command "c:\users\i319268\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\python.exe -u
> ```
>
> -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\i319268\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-b1nkbg30\scipy\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record C:\Users\i319268\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-06bz__e6-record\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\i319268\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-b1nkbg30\scipy\

I have also tried the unofficial SciPy wheel packages from Christoph Gohlke. When I try to install from his wheel packages, it gives an error like this:

> **C:\Projects\Kaggle>pip install scipy-0.18.1-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl**
>
> *scipy-0.18.1-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this*
>   *platform.*

I have already looked at StackOverflow for answers but I am completely stuck and unable to figure out anything. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "win32" in the .whl name means it is for 32-bit Python.  If you have 64-bit Python, you want one that says "amd64".  See if that works.

Comment: As @BrenBarn wrote: You need to get the right wheel version. You have got python 3.5 installed so you need to download wheel for 3.5 instead of 3.6

Comment: Thanks a lot @BrenBarn. It says SciPy got installed successfully.

But after that, when I try to import scipy in python code, it gives an error like this:

>>> import scipy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\i319268\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
    from numpy._distributor_init import NUMPY_MKL  # requires numpy+mkl
ImportError: cannot import name 'NUMPY_MKL'

Comment: If you use the installers from Gohlke's site, you need to use the Numpy MLK installer from that site too.  In my experience that is the easiest way to go on Windows (other than maybe Anaconda).

Comment: I see. I will try that and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot @BrenBarn Everything is up and running now.

Answer (score 4):

This has been solved. Thanks to @BrenBarn's help above in the comments I got everything up and running now.

The best way to get everything working in to use the wheel packages from [Christoph Gohlke](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

However, the main thing to note here is that you should use all the packages you want from his unofficial packages only as a number of packages might be dependent on other wheel packages. The other thing that one needs to keep in mind is to choose the proper version of the wheel packages (32bit or 64bit and the correct version of python as well [mainly mentioned in the wheel package name as cp]).

For example,

```
SciPy wheel package for 64bit system and Python 3.6: scipy‑0.18.1‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl

SciPy wheel package for 32bit system and Python 2.7: scipy‑0.18.1‑cp27‑cp27m‑win32.whl
```

Hope this will be helpful to others as well. Thanks for the help again @BrenBarn.